# Arrays giving me errors:: String subscript out of range; but everything seems to be in order

Tags: c++, arrays, winsock, directx-11

I've run into some problems with arrays, one while I was coding in Winsock and one in DirectX 11. In DirectX 11 its actually a texture array that I'm trying to release.

Here's the Winsock problem:

```
int retval;
    retval = recv(hclientSocket, tempBuffer, sizeof(tempBuffer), 0);
    if (retval == 0)
    {
        break; // Connection has been closed
    }
    else if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw ErrorHandler("Failed to receive due to socket");
    }
    else
    {
        Encyrption enc;
        string done = enc.Cipher(tempBuffer, retval);
        retval = retval * 3;
        cout << retval; // it prints out 3
        for (int i = 0; i < retval; i++) {
            tempBuffer[i] = done[i]; //the error is being pointed here on the 6th time it runs through this, even though its only suppose to go through this 3 times 
        }

        if (send(hclientSocket, tempBuffer, retval, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            throw ErrorHandler("Failed to send due to socket");
    }
```

okay most of this code I got from a Winsock tutorial place, but I wanted to try a different encryption method.

Here's the call function, because  originally intended to pass and return a string but this time I'm passing a `char*` and returning a string, which is converted in the above code.

The encryption takes in one character and turns it into a string of 3 for example a would become `bca` and `c` would become `cba` or something that's why I'm multiplying `retval` by 3. It prints out everything I want it to print out, but its giving an error after its done.

```
string pass = (string)message;
pass.resize(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (!isalnum(pass[i])) {
        return "\n";
    }
    else {
        return Cipher(pass);
    }
}
```

Okay so here's the Directx11 problem

I recently learned how to use multitextures utilizing a texture array, and Im having trouble releasing it.

```
#define TEXTURE_ELEMENTS_COUNT 2
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* m_textures[TEXTURE_ELEMENTS_COUNT];
for (int i = 0; i <= TEXTURE_ELEMENTS_COUNT; i++) {
    m_textures[i] = 0;
}
//some code here
for (int i = 1; i <= (TEXTURE_ELEMENTS_COUNT - 1); i++) {
    m_textures[i]->Release(); //it throws an exception right here, but I can't figure out why, I tried change `i` to zero, but it still throws it.
    m_textures[i] = 0;
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to look through my code, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and arrays sometimes throw me off, because its suppose to start at zero and sometimes its hard for me to visualize. Anyway thanks for any input in advance.

Comment: You got `<=` instead of `<` in 3rd line of 3rd code part

Answer (score 0):

Your element count is 2. Therefore you have an element at position 0 and at position 1.
So you have to start your loop at "i = 0" and end your loop after "i = 1". So start from 0 and run to "i < maxCount".

```
for (int i = 0; i < TEXTURE_ELEMENTS_COUNT; i++) { //FROM 0 TO i<MAXCOUNT
    m_textures[i] = 0; // HERE YOU CREATE A NULLPTR TO EVERY SRV
}
//some code here
for (int i = 0; i < (TEXTURE_ELEMENTS_COUNT); i++) { //USE THE SAME LOOP
    m_textures[i]->Release(); //IF THERE IS ALREADY A NULLPTR YOU HAVE AN INVALID ACCESS
    m_textures[i] = 0;
}
```

Try to use the Safe_Release function if you use the SDK. Otherwise define it for yourself.

```
SAFE_RELEASE(m_textures[i])
```

There is an included test for nullptr:

```
#ifndef SAFE_RELEASE
#define SAFE_RELEASE(x) 
   if(x != NULL)        
   {                    
     x->Release();     
     x = NULL;         
  }
#endif
```

Good Luck

Comment: during the "//some code" in line 4, i call `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile` so the null pointer isnt a problem, but then u pointed out that i should make sure that everything is created and call a safe release, instead i used `if(m_textures[i])` then `m_textures[i]->Release()`. However i am still getting the error. It says that its throwing the error "Access violation writing location 0xfdfdfdfd." but it could be solve if there was a handler. I read up on `0xfdfdfdfd` and people have said that its because im trying to access a freed variable.

Comment: but if it is indeed a freed variable wouldn't my if statement prevent it from being accessed? once again, thanks for taking ur time to read this

Comment: After freeing a variable, set the pointer to null. So you see very fast if its really freed. Maybe it is already freed but the pointer still points to some memory where there is no valid content anymore.